# In the late 1800s how did American Indians portray resiliency in the in the midst of oppression?

Tags: united-states

In the late 1800s how did American Indians portray resiliency in the in the midst of oppression?

Comment: nah, I just need a hint or something, not a direct answer to this question.

Comment: This appears to be a question that is purposely subjective, with the intent of providing the author an opportunity to dump all their knowledge on the subject without worry of being objectively wrong (as long as the argument can be supported). This is great for school essays, but is simply not the kind of question we can field here. Our format requires objectively answerable questions. If your own research on this topic turns up a question that looks objectively answerable, feel free to ask that here.

Comment: While the homework / essay question angle has been addressed as a closure reason, "Portrayals" or works of art are normally not historicised except as widespread practices.  You'd want a literature stack exchange for the details of *portrayals* themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Note that the subject line of your posting and the main text differ. How do you know that this is about First Nations?
- The Native Americans showed resilience by **not dying** in the face of persecution and deprivation. So how did they do that?

  - Your time period might include events like Little Big Horn (1876). Was fighting back a sign of resilience or did it only lead to events like Wounded Knee (1890)?
  - When did they start to go to reservations? What did they gain by doing so? Was that a good move at the time? What about those who did not go?
  - When could and did they leave the reservations again? What did that do to group cohesion? Was that a good move at the time? What about those who did not leave?